# .NET Core application cannot access to symbol link that created by mklink from other machine (Windows)

Tags: .net-core, mklink

My application runs on two servers, we need to share resource/assets among them by creating another Windows machine.

However, our application (running on .NET Core 2.1) cannot access to shared resource.

Please help me, thanks.

1. Tried to config symbol link by mklink.
2. Grant permission

Comment: _"My application run on two servers, we need to share resource/assets among them by creating another Windows machine."_ - that sounds a bit _sus_ to me - please explain how and why you came to that conclusion.

Comment: _"however, our application (run on dotnetcore 2.1) cannot access to shared resource."_ - why are you still running on .NET Core 2.1? It's unsupported - but updating to .NET 7 (currently supported) should be straightforward (VS2022 license notwithstanding).

Comment: This is my first task to move all resources to new server without guideline. On current server, it still works.

Comment: and yes, we will migrate to new dotnetcore version in near future